# How do I change a ceiling fan from switched light, pull-chain fan to just all switch controlled?

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling-fan

Originally my son's fan was wired so that the 1 light switch he has in his room turned on the fan's light then the pull cord on the fan turned the fan on separately, even when the light switch was “off”.

I actually just changed the fan so it operates on a remote and was hoping to return the switch to just doing the 1-way where the switch turns on or cuts off all power to the fan.

When I installed the fan, I used the wires that I had disconnected off the old fan. I capped grounds together, black to black, white to white, capped off the blue wire that came on the fan, then capped the red wire (which I figured was the solution here since we didn’t need that separate hot).

I opened up the light switch and I’m seeing both black and white wires, together, on the top nut of the switch then the red wire pushed into the bottom slot of the switch.

Is there another way I need to be wiring the switch on the wall? Or is there something I need to do to the fans wiring?

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] to include clear pictures of the wiring at both the switch and the fan. Those will often show us things that a text description does not...

Comment: Having the black and white connected together at the switch, would mean that white is change to hot or switch hot.  Connecting the whites together at the fan will probably give fireworks if you turn on the breaker and the switch.  Pictures will help a lot.

Comment: What make and model of remote are you using, and are you heart-set on it, or is changing it to something else an option? Also, can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: I think I’ve solved this. I took the ceiling fan down and found: power supply Black/White/Ground and switch Red/Black/White/ground. I tied black power supply and white switch, white power supply and white fan, black switch and black fan, and grounds together then I capped off red. Then on the switch on the wall, I capped off red, black went to the top, ground connected, and white at the bottom. Fan and light now work via Hunter Minimus remote when light switch on and all turn off when light switch off (and remote can no longer turn anything on when light switch off).

Comment: Given that you **have the wires in the cable,**  you should not be using white hot in old switch loop style. White neutral to switch location (modern code, cap off at switch box if not needed now) black unswitched hot to switch location, red switched hot from switch location. Be nice to the next person, it might even be you.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Ah didn’t try to cut corners, was just trying to follow a diagram (old school one?) I found online. So you’re saying now to cap off white at the switch, put red into the switch. Then at the fan I should connect switch’s red to power supply black?

Comment: Unless you have two switches (where you'd need to maintain the grandfathered white-hot switch loop) the "normal, standard, won't surprise anyone" arrangement is that power supply black should connect to switch black, power supply white to switch (location) white and fan white, switch red to fan black. Red is conventionally **switched** hot, That isn't a code requirement, but it reduces surprises to follow the established convention.